# How to configure In-Memory database when testing?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have checked some websites from apple, most appear to be outdated and lacking because I needed convert the code after pasting them into `XCode8`.  I have an old code but I can't figure out how to migrate them to the new style.

Here is my old code:

```
    self.psc = {
    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    do {
        _ = try psc.addPersistentStore(
         ofType: NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: nil,
        at: nil, options: nil)
    } catch {
    fatalError()
}

return psc
```

Here is what I have done so far,

```
    lazy var testPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Test Data Store")

    do {
        try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType:
            NSInMemoryStoreType, configurationName: "Test Persistent Store",
                                 at: nil, options: [:])
    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
```

There is exception in the try statement.

> Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)" fatal error:
>   Unresolved error nilError

Comment: Please check below answer. If it helps you, only you can tick it as answer. It will help other SO user to resolve same kind issue.

Comment: I made a mistake, I was supposed to tick the answer but clicked the upvote instead.  Thank you so much for the answer, it did help!

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. anyways you can do both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** continue using the old approach. It's **not** deprecated, and `NSPersistentContainer` isn't required.

If you want the newer approach, use the new `NSPersistentStoreDescription` class, which handles all the stuff that could be specified when adding a persistent store.

You can try below code for newer approach :

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")

            // Need to add NSPersistentStoreDescription ===
            let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
            description.type = NSInMemoryStoreType
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

            container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [weak self](storeDescription, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    NSLog("CoreData error \(error), \(error._userInfo)")
                    self?.errorHandler(error)
                }
                })
            return container
        }()
```

Hope this help you.